# Read the header of an MQ message

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am getting a message from MQ with the following code

```
MQQueue queue = mqManager.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
gmo.WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED;

queue.Get(message, gmo);

string message = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
```

The problem is I need access to the header information of this message as well. Namely the userId from whom the message was sent which is found in the header information. How can I access the header information of the message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access the [Userid property of MQMessage](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm) - i.e., `message.UserId`

> `public string UserId { get; set; }`
>   UserId is part of the identity context of the message. The queue manager generally provides the value. You can override the value if you have authority to set the identity context.

Comment: How to read other headers from MQ Message? Like if I want to read header called "type" from the message, then how to write a code to read it?

Comment: @AnilSoman follow the link in the answer, and there's a list of properties, such as Format, MessageType etc (depends on what you actually mean by type)